# What Visual Studio Code extension is good for 3 way (or 4 way) merging?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am currently learning Visual Studio Code. I come from a WebStorm background. Is there an option or extension to merge 3 ways?

Where in Visual Studio Code can I merge conflicts?

At the moment, I  thought I had resolved all the changes but when I run `git status` it says there are still unmerged paths?

Where can I see these unmerged paths in VSCode or else when do I know when I merged everything?

Answer (score 17):

Update for v1.72: see [Merge Editor: Provide a 4-editor view which also shows the base editor](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155277) (also known as 4-way merge to some):

> The next version will have an (optional) base pane:

```
'Mixed Layout With Base'
merge.mixedLayoutWithBase
```

[image: 4-way merge with base editor]

---

Three-way merge (3-way merge) is being built into vscode v1.69.  See [Release notes; 3-way merge](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#3-way-merge-editor),

> In this release, we continued working on the 3-way merge editor. This
> feature can be enabled by setting `git.mergeEditor` to true and will
> be enabled by default in future releases.
>
> The merge editor allows you to quickly resolve Git merge conflicts.
> When enabled, the merge editor can be opened by clicking on a
> conflicting file in the Source Control view. Checkboxes are available
> to accept and combine changes in Theirs or Yours:

[image: demo of 3-way merge]

> All language features are available in the merge editor (including
> diagnostics, breakpoints, and tests), so you get immediate feedback
> about any issues in the merged result.
>
> The result can also be edited directly. Note how the checkbox update
> as expected:

[image: further demo of 3-way merge]

> When closing the merge editor or accepting the merge, a warning is
> shown if not all conflicts have been addressed.
>
> The merge editor supports word-level merging - as long as the changes
> don't intersect, both sides can be applied. If the insertion order
> matters, it can be swapped. At any time, the conflict can also be
> resolved manually.

[image: demo 3 of 3-way merge]

Answer (score 8):

I wasn't able to find a working VSCode extension that let you right click and launch the merge tool for a specific file, so I wrote the [Git Diff and Merge Tool extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=david-rickard.git-diff-and-merge-tool).

This requires registering the merge tool with Git:

`git config --global --edit`

The specific values depend on which tool you are integrating. This is what I have for Beyond Compare 4:

```
[diff]
    tool = beyondcompare4
[difftool "beyondcompare4"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\bcomp.exe\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
[merge]
    tool = beyondcompare4
[mergetool]
    keepbackup = false
[mergetool "beyondcompare4"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\bcomp.exe\" \"$REMOTE\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$MERGED\"
    trustexitcode = true
```

`keepbackup = false` prevents the system from creating .orig backup files after a merge. `trustexitcode = true` tells Git that the diff tool's exit code can be trusted to determine the outcome of the merge.

Answer (score -9):

When you resolve one file, add it using `git add filename` to stage. When all conflict files resolved, you can go wieh `git merge --continue`. It's about git workflow not vscode.

Read this: https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/